# How to "not build" from branch if build for other branch is in progress or failed?

Tags: git, jenkins

Using Jenkins, we have multi-branch pipelines in place for our repos. We have builds run automatically for our `dev`/`qa` branches. So if a `dev` build is in progress for a given repo, or if the latest build of the `dev` branch was not successful, we want to hold off on any automatic build from the `qa` branch. E.g. "don't promote broken `dev` builds to `qa`.

Is there a way to accomplish this with Jenkins? Of course we would like to be able to trigger a manual build from `qa` which would bypass this rule.

Comment: you could use a global variable and set the value if dev passes and if not skip qa deployment

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has an API : you can query Jenkins for the state of the last build of your pipeline for the `dev` branch.